# Error with QCA link library on Qt5 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, qt-creator, ubuntu-16.04

I built successfully qca under ubuntu LTS 16.04.
The command :

```
./qcatool-qt5 plugins
```

return :

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin
Available Providers:
qca-gcrypt
qca-gnupg
qca-logger
qca-ossl
```

QtCreator finds normally all qca files with 
`INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/Qca-qt5/QtCrypto/` 
in my .pro file. On compilation, the compiler returns 
`/usr/bin/ld cannot find -lqca` 
while i have 
`LIBS += -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/crypto -lqca` 
in my .pro file.
The command 
`ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/crypto` prints

```
libqca-gcrypt.so libqca-gnupg.so libqca-logger.so libqca-nss.so libqca-ossl.so libqca-softstore.so
```

Any idea guys ??? and i'm using Qt 5.9 installed at `/home/user/Qt/5.9`, my openssl version is 1.1.0
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After hours, i found the problem,
i should write `-lqca-qt5` instead of `-lqca`